# Confusion about Python's distribution packages

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm going over [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) about packaging  Python projects, and I'm quite confused. It provides an example of creating a distribution package, by creating the following structure:

```
packaging_tutorial/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── src/
│   └── example_package/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── example.py
└── tests/
```

The `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` files contains pretty much (or exactly) the same data bits.
In the "Creating Pyproject.toml" section the tutorial says:

> pyproject.toml tells build tools (like pip and build) what is required to build your project. This tutorial uses setuptools, so open pyproject.toml and enter the following content:

When it gets to the "Generating distribution archives" part it says to do this with PyPA's build package.

```
py -m build
```

So what I don't understand is: we have three files here: `setup.py`, `setup.cfg` and `Pyproject.toml`. What build system are we using to create the package? Is it setuptools or PyPA build? Which files are required for which system? On the one hand, the tutorial says that we're using `setuptools`, but then it tells me to run `py -m build`.. what gives?

My guess is - please correct me if I'm wrong - that `setup.py` is using `setuptools`, and if I'm using this file to install the package, I don't need `setup.cfg` nor `Pyproject.toml`. I just run

```
py -m pip install .
```

And the package is installed on my machine.

Comment: https://blog.pilosus.org/posts/2019/12/26/python-third-party-tools-configuration/

Comment: In short, `setup.py` is a script that uses a hard-coded library; it uses whatever build tool it's written to use. `setup.cfg`, on the other hand, is a tool-agostic configuration file, so you use whatever tool you like, as long as it supports the use of `setup.cfg`. `Pyproject.toml` is the same, but with an attempt at providing a standard file format that's nicer to use than the decades-old `.ini` format used by `setup.cfg`.

Comment: You don't have a `setup.py` file here, so why are you asking about `setup.py`? It is uncommon to have _both_ a `setup.py` and a `pyproject.toml`, usually you would have just one or the other.